# Open-source webmail client that works with GMail API easily

Tags: web, smtp, imap, gmail-api, webmail

Excuse me for my stupid question, but I am a complete newbie to webmail clients, SMTP & IMAP, etc. So, my question is, is there any open-source webmail client that can work easily with Gmail API, like for example, to visualize emails, folders, settings, to send messages and so on? I am trying to connect to Gmail with NodeJS. So, when I finally got the data, what is the next step?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to use NodeJS to create a web client for Gmail when Gmail has already been invented, is a web client, works great and is Free?

Comment: We are developing an web app in which we want to have a webmail client for the user email. @suchislife

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Below there are 2 NodeJS modules that can greatly speed up your implementations.

[node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) which is an IMAP client module for node.js.

[nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) which is a SMTP module for Node.js applications to allow easy as cake email sending.